# How to affect the snapshot Android takes from application when going to background

Tags: android

My question is about the Android system taking snapshot of application screen when entering background. I have some secure content in application which I would like to hide in that point, so if user enters background and opens recent apps, I could show always the same content (for example splash screen) for my application instead of the last screen visible before entered to background.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Please do not post answers about FLAG_SECURE, I do not want the screen to be black and also found a bug from it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64086

Comment: I've suggested another workaround, maybe you can try that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa nope, haven't tried this after this post. Might be possible to do since its few years ago :)

Comment: I have tried this using `boolean Activity.onCreateThumbnail()` but it never gets called on API 22 and 24

Comment: Looking at this post it seems that theres still no good solution on this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370

Answer (score 0):

Use [FLAG_SECURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) .

**Usage:**

```
  public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                      LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

             setContentView(R.layout.main);
      }
  }
```

That will prevent from a screenshot being taken of that activity. And will show a blank screen for that app in the recent apps list.

**Edit:**

Other than `FLAG_SECURE` there doesn't seem any method to prevent  a  screenshot from being taken. However, I'd suggest this unclean workaround instead. I've not tried this, just an idea:

1. Override the `onPause()` and `onBackPressed()` methods of the Activity. So when the home or back button are pressed, these are called.
2. Then , inside these, use `setContentView()` to show another dummy view or a splash screen for that matter. So that this splash view becomes the last shown View.
3. **After** point 2, call `super.onPause()` or `super.onBackPressed()` , so that the screenshot is taken, of this splash screen. Don't call them before point 2.

Comment: @Niko Looks like there is no other method..I even tried clearing the app from the stack top, but that doesn't work either. Such a stupid implementation, this.

Comment: Atleast there is no public API, but might be some hack with the platform private members/methods. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @Niko could u achieve the above with pause/resume?.. i know i am late..its 2016 now :)